# JQuery Mobile works on Browser but not on a mobile phone

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, phonegap

The following code works fine on chrome, but once I convert it into apk through phonegap and I install it on the android phone, I see a white blank page! Any idea why this is the case?

**index.html** - the main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on("pagecontainerload", function(event, ui) {
        console.log('navigating to page1...');
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#page1");
        console.log('navigating done!');
      });
      console.log('loading pagecontainers...');
      $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load", "page1.html");
      $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load", "page2.html");
      console.log('pagecontainer-load done!');
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

**page_1.html**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-dom-cache="true">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#page2" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">Go To Page 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And **page_2.html**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-dom-cache="true">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#page1" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">Go Back To Page 1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Connect your mobile and check for error in console.

Comment: How can I do that ? connect mobile to what ?

Comment: Connect your mobile to your Development machine. Type "chrome://inspect" in URL.

Comment: Refer this link.  https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/using-remote-chrome-devtools-to-debug-android-cordova-apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, it seems so simple !
I have put the JQuery .js and JQuery Mobile .js and .css files in local, rather than call them from CDN.
It just works fine !